# Prove the equation in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

> Which of the following equations is true in the complex numbers?  Prove it.
>
> $$\Bigl(\frac{1+i \tan a}{1-i \tan a}\Bigr)^n = \frac{1+i \tan a}{1-i \tan a}$$
>
> $$\Bigl(\frac{1+i \tan a}{1-i \tan a}\Bigr)^n = \frac{1+ i \tan na}{1- i \tan na}$$

Comment: @orion yes. I used "i(sina/cosa) = i tana" ,then by getting common denominator I omitted "cosa" ,reached to "[(cosa +i sina)/(cosa - isina)]^n" .then what should I do?

Comment: I guess you forgot an $a$ in the second case: $\tan n$ should be $\tan na$

Comment: @egreg yes.edited

Comment: The first identity implies that the fraction is $0$ or an $n-1^{th}$ root of the unit, which cannot be true for arbitrary $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
1+i\tan a&=1+i\frac{\sin a}{\cos a}=
\frac{\cos a+i\sin a}{\cos a}
\\[6px]
1-i\tan a&=1-i\frac{\sin a}{\cos a}=
\frac{\cos(-a)+i\sin(-a)}{\cos a}
\end{align}
Now recall [De Moivre’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

By the way, you can easily disprove the first equality by using $a=\pi/4$ and $n=2$, because in this case the left-hand side is
$$
\Bigl(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\Bigr)^2\ne\frac{1+i}{1-i}
$$
Of course the (second) equality holds provided $\tan a$ and $\tan na$ exist.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first lets consider the term $$\frac{1+i\tan(a)}{1-i\tan(a)}$$
if we multpily both top and bottom by $1+i\tan(a)$ we get $$\frac{(1+i\tan(a))^2}{1 + \tan^2(a)}$$

and by using the identity $\sec^2(a) = 1 + \tan^2(a)$ and expanding the numerator we get
$$\cos^2(a)+2i\tan(a)\cos^2(a) - \tan^2(a)\cos^2(a)$$
$$= \cos^2(a) + 2i\sin(a)\cos(a) - \sin^2(a)$$
$$\implies \frac{1+i\tan(a)}{1-i\tan(a)} = (\cos(a) + i\sin(a))^2$$

Ok now since we have this we can work out what $(\frac{1+i\tan(a)}{1-i\tan(a)})^n$ is
$$(\frac{1+i\tan(a)}{1-i\tan(a)})^n = (\cos(a) + (i\sin(a))^2)^n$$
And by De Moivre's theorem we get 
$$(\cos(na) + i\sin(na))^2$$

Using the identity we derived before $\frac{1+i\tan(a)}{1-i\tan(a)} = (\cos(a) + i\sin(a))^2$ we get that $$(\frac{1+i\tan(a)}{1-i\tan(a)})^n = \frac{1 + \tan(na)}{1-\tan(na)}$$

Comment: Use \ before the trig name to set it properly in Latex i.e \cos (x) gives $\cos(x)$ which is easier to read than $cos (x)$

Comment: @Mattos Sorry, didnt know you could do that, I edited my answer

Comment: No need to apologise, I was just giving you a tip for future reference. It looks good now. Also, if you need to put brackets around a fraction, use '\left (' and '\right )' so that the brackets are big enough to fit the entire term inside.

Answer (score 0):

By De Moivre,$$\left(\frac{1+i\tan a}{1-i\tan a}\right)^n=\left(\frac{\cos a+i\sin a}{\cos a-i\sin a}\right)^n=\frac{\cos na+i\sin na}{\cos na-i\sin na}=\frac{1+i\tan na}{1-i\tan na}.$$